# Server unexpectedly closed network connection in ftp and putty - Amazon server

Tags: amazon-ec2

we are using amazon server and the Instance works fine. But, suddenly it stops in ftp and shows the below error:

```
Error:  Server unexpectedly closed network connection  
Error:  Could not connect to server.
```

But, instance is running correctly and adminer also opens fine. Only ftp and putty does not open.

Comment: Are you trying to download/upload huge files that takes long time using ftp due to slow internet connection?

Comment: yes, i upload the huge multiplt files

Comment: How much time it takes to download / upload a huge single file??

Comment: don't know correctly, but me and my colleague were upload all the files by eve when office close. so the files will be uploaded till morning. This process will be done for two days

Comment: May be this answer can solve your problem : http://stackoverflow.com/a/15216962/1144932

Comment: but i'm using windows system. although putty also not connected.